# Different authorization header for each operation in a Guzzle client service description

Tags: guzzle, guzzle-service-description

The API I'm accessing requires a custom authorization header that is a combination of the publicKey that is passed in when the client is instantiated and the complete URI of the API endpoint. I want to pull the baseUrl and operation uri out of the service description and use them to create the authorization header, but I can't figure out how to do this when calling the instantiated client.

This is the service description:

```
{
"name": "FranchiseSystem",
"apiVersion": "1",
"baseUrl": "https://apidev.example.com",
"description": "REST API client",
"operations": {
    "GetFranchiseList": {
        "httpMethod": "GET",
        "uri": "v1/franchise",
        "summary": "Returns an array of franchises."
    },
    "GetReviews": {
        "httpMethod": "GET",
        "uri": "v1/review",
        "summary": "Returns an array of reviews."
    }
}
}
```

This is the client setup:

```
$testClient = new JunknetClient([
  'publicKey' => '1234567890',
]);
```

This is the call to the instantiated client with the name of the operation:

```
$result = $testClient->GetFranchiseList();
```

or:

```
$result = $testClient->GetReviews();
```

When testClient->GetFranchiseList is called, I need to create the authorization header using the publicKey and the values of baseUrl and uri for GetFranchiseList.

When testClient->GetReviews is called, I need to create the authorization header using the publicKey and the values of baseUrl and uri for GetReviews.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at the following links from the Guzzle docs.

1. [Request Options - Headers](http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/clients.html#headers)
2. [Authentication Parameters](http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/clients.html#auth)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've got the authentication header working, but only when I manually construct the custom auth string outside of the client and then pass it in to the client. The problem is that I need to access values that are only available at call time (from the service description)to construct the auth string when I call the API. I don't know how to do this, or if it's even possible.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my problem by using and event emitter and subscriber. It's a bit messy, but it get's the job done.

```
private function handleCredentialsOptions(Collection $config) {
  //Build authorization header from $config values
$this->getHttpClient()->getEmitter()->on('before',
  function (BeforeEvent $e) use(&$config) {
    $this->getHttpClient()->setDefaultOption('headers', [
      'Authentication' => '',
    ]);
    $path = $e->getRequest()->getUrl();
    $authValue = $config['publicKey'].';;';
    $authValue .= time().';';
    $authValue .= strtoupper(md5($config['privateKey'] . $path));
    $this->getHttpClient()->setDefaultOption('headers', [
      'Authentication' => $authValue,
    ]);
  });
}
```